# Displaying part of every child page?

Tags: theme-development, pages

I have been trying to find a way to return page information in order to create a landing page. I have done this with posts before, to create a blog reel, and would like to achieve the same overall result with pages.

**The Scenario:**
I use a drop menu with pages created in the WordPress. Nesting the pages builds the menu.

**The Goal:**
I would like to get the subpages of the parent page. When a user navigates to the parent page I would like it to return links to the subpages with a part of the content of the child page. For example, I would like to display the `<div>` with class `header`.

**A Starting Point:**

```
$mypages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');

foreach($mypages as $page)
{
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if(!$content) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content ?></div>
<?php
}
```

So far function returns all of `the_content` for all of the children and grandchildren pages. I would like it to specifically return **only 1 div with a specific class** from each child page and **disregard all of the grandchildren** pages.

Comment: What does `echo '<pre>Pages: '; print_r($mypages); echo '</pre>';` output?

Comment: @patrick: Where do you define a static page ID? You use `$post->ID` in the `get_pages()` call, doesn't this always refer to the current page ID?

Comment: @ Jan: Thanks for the heads up, how can I use it to select current page?

Comment: @kaiser: right now as is the entire content for all of the pages. Is there a way to filter specific content based on div ids?

Comment: @Jan: It is now using the current page, just need to filter the content so I am not getting ALL the content from each page.

Comment: @patrick: It's not really clear what your problem is: getting the child pages of the current page, or getting a part of these pages? If it is the latter, which part? Can you please edit your question to give examples of what you currently get and what you want to get?

Comment: @Jan, thanks for your patience. It is the latter... Right now the function returns ALL the data from 'the_content' and I would like it to only return a div with a specific id

Comment: @patrick: OK, can you specify what div it should be? What is the ID based on? Do you have an example of a full page, so we can see the div in context?

Comment: @Jan: Here is an example http://challengesunlimited.com/wordpress/about-us/ where the landing page returns all of the children/grandchildren page. If you look at the source you will see each `<div class="layoutset" id="hdr">`. This is the div I am trying to return.

Comment: @patrick: OK, so you want to select the `<div>` with ID `hdr` from each post? And then probably rename the ID, to prevent ID collisions?

Comment: @patrick - i really don't get around what you're trying to acchieve. Anyway: This is how you'd receive an array of all parent/ancestor pages `$GLOBALS['post']->ancestors` and this is how you'd receive the parent of the current page `$GLOBALS['post']->post_parent`

Comment: @jan: Yes, thats correct, but I can just as easilly make a unique class and select that instead to avoid id collisions

Comment: @kaiser: Thanks for your support, but I think I've almost got it sorted out here with Jan

Comment: @patrick: I re-wrote your question, based on your comments. Is this what you had in mind? Otherwise feel free to roll it back. Is it always the first `<div>` you want to display? Would it be acceptable if the user had to "split up" the page using the *More* button? This is a bit easier to search for.

Comment: @patrick - Ok. I upvoted @Jan Fabry comments. Please don't forget to mark Jans answer as solution. :)

Comment: @patrick - to 'disregard all of the grandchildren', use the 'parent' parameter for your 'get_pages()' together with the 'child_of' parameter (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Comment: @Michael: good suggestion! Note that `'parent' => $post->ID` must be combined with `'hierarchical' => false`, or no results will be output.

Comment: @Jan, I am not sure that there is a More button in the page... Either way I am trying not to display anything more then header content (title+tagline). Can we use the more button to do that?

Comment: @Michael: That makes sense, but I am not sure how to write that with the syntax... would it be like this: `$mypages = get_pages('child_of&parent='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');`

Comment: @patrick - `$mypages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&parent='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. To output your "Loop" only for Child Pages, and not for Grandchild etc. Pages, add a conditional.

e.g.

```
foreach ( $mypages as $page ) {
     if ( $page->post_parent == $post->ID ) {
          // Loop goes here
     }
}
```

1. To output only an excerpt of each Child Page, enable excerpt support for Pages, and then output `$page->post_excerpt`.

In `functions.php`:

```
add_post_type_support('page', 'excerpt');
```

Then in your "Loop":

```
foreach ( $mypages as $page ) {

     if ( $page->post_parent == $post->ID ) {

              $content = $page->post_excerpt; // changed post_content to post_excerpt

              if( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
                   continue;

              $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
              ?>
              <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>
              <div class="entry"><?php echo $content ?></div>
              <?php

     }
}
```

Comment: I have added support for pages and tried the new loop, but it just returns blank.

Comment: My thinking was that you could put the custom excerpt content into the "Excerpt" form field on the Edit Page screen - i.e. the content within the specified `<div>` tags.

Comment: I do not get a custom excerpt field. Does this mean I have not added support correctly?

Comment: Did you check "Screen Options", to ensure that the "Excerpt" field is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

And here is my solution to split it with the *More* button (which is also available for pages):

```
$child_pages = get_pages( array(
    'parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'sort_column' => 'post_date',
    'sort_order' => 'desc',
) );

foreach ( $child_pages as $child_page ) {
    $short_content = $child_page->post_content;
    if ( preg_match( '/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $short_content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ) ) {
        $short_content = substr( $short_content, 0, $matches[0][1] );
    }
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $short_content );
}
```